# Refactor and obfuscate all variable names in java

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I tried ProGuard with NetBeans to obfuscate the class. After decompiling I see that it's only renaming local variables names.

Can anyone help explain to me how to refactor all variables names including public members. I can do that myself in NetBeans but it'll take forever.  Also, ProGuard is obfuscating everything, even the libraries; I want to obfuscate only my classes.  It doesn't matter if libraries are obfuscated or not.

For example, my global class contains variables like this:

```
public class D {
    public static boolean doneSplash = false;
    public static boolean bossActive = false;
.....
```

Is there a way to make it like ...

```
public class D {
    public static boolean asdsa6d = false;
    public static boolean xgrrret7 = false;
.....
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Renaming public fields is a visible change. I can understand the obfuscators don't do that.

Comment: Do you have some `-keep` options in your config file?

Comment: @zeroflagL yes , if i remove <keepclassmembers> proGuard is giving errors

Comment: So the real question is "Why do I get errors when I remove -keepclassmembers", right? Which errors?

Comment: i removed public access and error is The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

Comment: uhm dont bother a sleep made everything work i used proguard gui and unchecked skip non public class and class members and it worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use proguard gui and uncheck following option

```
skip non public library class 
skip non public library class members
```